# What is the consensus on the existence of infinite metallic fatigue life?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I'd like to know whether there are some metals which present an infinite fatigue life, i.e. they will never fail regardless of the number of cyclic stress applied. [Wikipedia (1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_limit#History) seems to indicate that there are no such materials, and it links to a [1999 paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1460-2695.1999.00183.x/abstract) called "There is no infinite fatigue life in metallic materials".

However I found the name of a [2011 paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0142112310001362) to be "Very high cycle fatigue – Is there a fatigue limit?" which seems to indicate that, back in 2011, the issue wasn't settled. I don't know as of today if we have finally settled it and what answer it is.

I also don't know if we can numerically simulate a solid with a cyclic stress from a quantum mechanical or semi-classical viewpoint and whether it's been done.